# How to pass ctx / context into KOA middleware that is imported (createShopifyAuth)?

Tags: shopify, next.js, koa, shopify-app

I'm looking to pass the request context into a KOA middleware that is generated from a require (https://github.com/Shopify/koa-shopify-auth). I set some API keys that I need to pass into it from a previous middleware but have no access to them when I reach createShopifyAuth.

I've tried passing in the global server.context but it doesn't seem to be set from the previous middleware.

```
server.use(async (ctx, next) => {
    await shopifyKeys;
    if (url.parse(ctx.originalUrl, true).query.shop) {
      const shops = url.parse(ctx.originalUrl, true).query.shop;
      server.context.keys = [shopifyKeys[shops].key, shopifyKeys[shops].secret];
      console.log(server.context.keys);
    }
    return next();
  });

server.use(
  createShopifyAuth({
    apiKey: server.context.keys[0],
    secret: server.context.keys[1],
    scopes: [
      'read_products',
      'read_checkouts',
      'read_orders',
      'write_orders',
    ],
    async afterAuth(ctx) {
      const { shop, accessToken } = ctx.session;
      ctx.cookies.set('shopOrigin', shop, {
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: 'none',
      });
      const registration = await registerWebhook({
        address: `${HOST}/webhooks/orders/paid`,
        topic: 'ORDERS_PAID',
        accessToken,
        shop,
        apiVersion: ApiVersion.July20,
      });

      if (registration.success) {
        console.log('Successfully registered webhook!');
      } else {
        console.log(
          'Failed to register webhook',
          registration.result.data.webhookSubscriptionCreate.userErrors,
        );
      }
      ctx.redirect('/');
    },
  }),
);
```

Any help with figuring out how to get the context into the second server.use would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am allegedly a newbie when it comes to KOA, but the only way I manage to make it was passing the data via cookies, **individually**. Here is an example:

```
  server.use(
    createShopifyAuth({
      apiKey: SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
      secret: SHOPIFY_API_SECRET_KEY,
      scopes: [
        "read_products",
        "write_products",
        "read_script_tags",
        "write_script_tags",
        "read_themes",
        "write_themes",
      ],
      accessMode: "offline",

      afterAuth(ctx) {
        const { shop, accessToken } = ctx.session;

        ctx.cookies.set("shopOrigin", shop, {
          httpOnly: false,
          secure: true,
          sameSite: "none",
        });

        ctx.cookies.set("accessToken", accessToken, {
          httpOnly: false,
          secure: true,
          sameSite: "none",
        });

        ctx.redirect("/");
      },
    }),
  );
```